# How to capture standard output of the process started by system()

Tags: iphone, ios, io-redirection

How do I save the output of `system("openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k secret -P -md sha1 > FILENAME")` into a file.

I have tried the following:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains

(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.txt",

                      documentsDirectory];

NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k secret -P -md sha1 > %s",[fileName UTF8String]];
NSLog(@"AES Key is %@",str);
system([str UTF8String]);

NSString *strAES = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileName encoding:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"strAES Key is %@",strAES);

NSString *strAESKey=[[[[strAES componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"strAESKey Key is %@",strAESKey);

// NSString *content = @"One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive";
  [str writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];`
```

Where am I going wrong ?

The `system()` function sends the output to the console but since the iPhone does not have a console, I need to redirect the output to a text file and get the key from the file to use it for encryption/decryption.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you are able to give more details about exactly what problem you faced, or in what way your solution above didn't work, then you are likely to get more constructive help/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: be aware, I don't think you can use `system(3)` on an not jail broken iOS. But I'm not sure, so I will explain how to do it:

This is a little bit tricky.

To achieve it, you have to know that each process gets opened with three file descriptors: one for reading (`stdin` for standard input) and two for writing (`stdout` for standard output and `stderr` for standard error output). They have the fd numbers 0 (`stdin`), 1 (`stdout`) and 2 (`stderr`).

To redirect standard output or standard error to a file from a program, you have to do the following:

- first, `fork(2)` the process. In the parent process `waitpid(2)` for the child prozess.
- In the child process:

  - reopen (`freopen(3)`) `stdout` and `stderr` to the file you want the output to be redirected.
  - use `execve(2)` to execute the program you want to call
  - when the command terminates, the parent gets a SIGCHLD and `waitpid(2)` should return

The number in the brackets describes the chapter in the man pages (`man 2 waitpid`, e.g.) for the function.

Hope this helps, if you have more questions, ask :-)

**Update:** Since the OP just wants to get the output and not specificly into a file, you can use `popen(3)`:

```
int status;
char value[1024];
FILE *fp = popen("openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k secret -P -md sha1", "r");

if (fp == NULL) exit(1); // handle error

while (fgets(value, 1024, fp) != NULL) {
  printf("Value: %s", value);
}

status = pclose(fp);
if (status == -1) {
  /* Error reported by pclose() */
}
else {
  /* Use macros described under wait() to inspect `status' in order
   to determine success/failure of command executed by popen() */
}
```

Comment: 1. On jailbroken iOS, there is a shell, so you can use the system function. 2. Why not just popen it? Then you don't have to deal with all those tedious function calls.

Comment: 1. Thanks, you are right, I edit my answer to be more specific. 2. If you just want to read the output, a `popen()` would be the right thing to do. If you want to redirect the output to a file, you should reopen stdout.

Comment: When i execute the below line 
  `system("openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k secret -P -md sha1");`
 It prints the output in console
**Output:
 salt=0879D963A2DF15F9
key=26287A322BE333C6A5E44256791AFEDE
iv =23715CAFB431BE252BD2AB20D56B9C42**
How can i fetch this data from console ?
Can u please give me sample for using popen() ?

Comment: Hi again the code doesn't work for device..but it runs on the simulator..  Can u please help me ?

Comment: Hi again the code doesn't work for device  **Its not going into the while loop on device ** but it runs on the simulator..  Can u please help me ?

Comment: That's what I was talking about. You cannot execute commands on the device because of the sandbox. You have to use the OpenSSL API (http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ssl.html)

Comment: We have used the openssl library in our project and were able to  generate the AES Key using the command but could not save the key.