# Debugging - How to log the folder trees in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, debugging

I want to log my application's folder trees in Xcode debug area just like the picture below.

In command line, I can use the command `tree` to log directory tree of a folder.

Is there a way to log folder trees like this in Xcode? I can log a array of files and folders in a folder, but I want a readable log not just a list.

And the folder path is in a iOS Application. `NSHomeDirectory()`, for example.

[image: directory tree]

Answer (score 0):

As this is just for debugging just run `tree`, grab its output, and `NSLog` it. Look up `system(3)`, `popen(3)` in `man` and `NSTask` in the frameworks for how to run a command.

**Addendum after Comment**

Apologies, when I read:

> In command line, I can use the command `tree` to log directory tree of a folder.

I did not check the actual command. Is `tree` available on any version of MacOS?

Given the lack of this command you can roll your own. Look up `fts(3)`. With these library routines you can write a simple loop which will traverse a complete folder hierarchy and print the items as you go. You will have the item kind, depth and name to use to produce your output.

HTH

Comment: According to [How to capture standard output of the process started by system()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14753068/6279975), I use `popen("tree ./", "r")`, I get `sh: tree: command not found`, how can I do?  And this is just valid for Mac Application not iOS?

Comment: Added an addendum for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to write the function to log folder trees by myself.